# Retrieve the passing argument of a Promise in .then

Tags: javascript, promise

I need some help with handling multiple promises at the same time.

I have a Promise `foo(value)` provided by a `Library`. I trigger this function on an array of value :

```
for (var i=0; i<this.array.length; i++) {
    var aPromise = Library.foo(this.array[i]);
    aPromise.then(function(result) {
        //I NEED TO KNOW HERE THE VALUE OF this.array[i] LINKED TO THE ACTUAL PROMISE RESULT
        alert(array[i]/*not working*/ + " return > " + result);
    }).catch[...];
}
```

I do not find a way to get a link between the which argument has been used to trigger the promise and the actual result of it. Is there a clean way to do it ?

- The Promise is provided by an external Library that I cannot modify.
- I tried to create my own Promise calling that Promise so I can build my own returned object with the inputs and output but I was unsuccessful.

Thanks !

Comment: Have the promise return its input in addition to its result.

Comment: I though about that but the Promise is provided by an external Library that I cannot modify. I tried to create my own Promise calling that Promise so I can build my own returned object with the inputs and output but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: `array[i]` would be working if your callback would close over `i`.

Comment: That worked ! Thanks